# Why am I always getting a rock response from p2, p3 and p4?

Tags: ruby

Hi I'm just learning ruby and decided to try and eloborate on codewars Kata to create quick rock, paper, scissors game. At first I was getting random responses but now it's alway rock. Please help and sorry if this is ridiculously easy.

```
module Promtable
  def prompt(message = "What would you like to do? ", symbol = ":> ")
    print message
    print symbol
    var = gets.chomp.to_s
    if !var.match /rock|paper|scissors/
     puts "I'm sorry that is not a valid response please try again"
     print message
     print symbol
     gets.chomp
    else
     var
   end
  end
end

def rps(p1, p2)
    if @p1 == 'rock' && @p2 == 'scissors'
      puts "Player 1 won!"
    elsif 
       @p1 == 'paper' && @p2 == 'rock'
      puts "Player 1 won!"
    elsif 
       @p1 == 'scissors' && @p2 == 'paper'
      puts "Player 1 won!"
    elsif 
       @p1 == 'rock' && @p2 == 'paper'
      puts "Computer won!"
    elsif 
       @p1 == 'scissors' && @p2 == 'rock'
      puts "Computer won!"
    elsif 
       @p1 == 'paper' && @p2 == 'scissors'
      puts "Computer won!"
    else 
       puts "It's a draw!" 
    end
end

def game
  include Promtable 
  p1 = prompt("Player 1 plays...?")
  choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
  p2 = choices[rand]
  p3 = choices[rand]
  p4 = choices[rand]

  rps(p1, p2)
  puts "The computer chose #{p2}!"

  p1 = prompt("What's your second choice...? ")
  p3 = choices[rand]

  rps(p1, p3)
  puts "The computer chose #{p3}!"

  p1 = prompt("What's your final choice...? ")
  p4 = choices[rand]

  rps(p1, p4)
  puts "The computer chose #{p4}!"
end

puts "Hi welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors"
game

puts "Would you like to play again? (Y/N)"
 var = gets.chomp.downcase
 if var.match /y/
  game
end
```

Comment: Consider using a hash: `h = { :rock=>:scissors, :scissors=>:paper, :paper=>:rock }`. Then if player 1 plays `c1` and player 2 plays `c2`, where `c1` and `c2` are each  `:rock`, `:paper` or `:scissors`, player 1 wins if `h[c1] == c2`, player 2 wins if `h[c2] == c1`, else it's a tie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues. One which has already been pointed out about the default return value of `rand`. I recommend using `choices.sample`. The other issue is in `rps`: note that `p1` and `@p1` are different variables. There's no need to use instance variables in `rps`; I'd change them all to local `p1` and `p2`.

Now, some code review style comments:

It's cool that you are experimenting with mixins with the module `Promtable` (which is missing a 'p' by the way). Of course you have some RPS logic embedded in it, so it isn't really reusable. Maybe you can make it more generic by adding a way to pass in an array of valid values. Speaking of valid values, you are checking them with a regular expression (`/rock|paper|scissors/`) which just checks a substring. If I were to type "rocky" it would pass through and be treated as a draw. You may want to use 
`if !valid_values.include? var` or `unless valid_values.include? var` instead of the regex.

The `rps` method can be simplified in a number of ways. Cary Swoveland had a clever idea in the comments of using a hash to look up the winning combinations. Another way to simplify would be to use a `case` statement:

```
case [p1,p2]
when ['rock', 'scissors'], ['paper', 'rock'], ['scissors', 'paper']
  puts "Player 1 won!"
when ['scissors', 'rock'], ['rock', 'paper'], ['paper', 'scissors']
  puts "Computer won!"
else
  puts "It's a draw!"
end
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help and advice, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`rand` returns a number between 0 and 1. Essentially, `choices[rand]` always becomes `choices[0]`.

You may want to use `choices[rand(0..2)]` instead.

Alternatively, you could use `choices.sample`.

Check the docs for `rand` [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Random.html#method-i-rand).